# Is there a way to have a div's width equal to 100% until a breakpoint, after which its width is 30%

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a div

```html
<body style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
  <div id="containerDiv">
    <div id="canvasDiv" />
  </div>
</body>
```

How would I be able to make `canvasDiv` 30% the width of `containerDiv` on large screens and, at a certain screen width size and below, make `canvasDiv` 100% the width of `containerDiv`?

A hint/suggestion usign Bootstrap would be preferable (and probably easier as well). So far, I have it partially figured out; if I do

```html
<body style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
  <div id="containerDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div id="canvasDiv" class="container-md m-md-0" />
  </div>
</body>
```

then `canvasDiv` is 100% of `containerDiv`'s width below Bootstrap's `md` breakpoint (768px) and 720px wide above the `md` breakpoint. Is there a way I can (without using Sass) override this and make it 30% instead of 720px?

I realize as I'm writing this that I may be asking two separate questions. An answer to either would be nice. Also, I could not find any resources on the web for doing something like this; **I would appreciate a redirection to a related topic**, as I do want to understand the what and how, instead of just having an answer.

Answer (score 0):

with css:

```
         @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
             #canvasDiv {
                 width: 30vw;
             }
         }
```